# How to return deep serialized object (with complex type properties) in Asp.Net web api?

Tags: .net, serialization, asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-web-api

I have next classes:

```
public class Event
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<ImageLink> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImageLink
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

My action:

```
public IQueryable<Event> GetEvents()
{
    var events = EventsRepository.Events.AsQueryable();
    return events;
}
```

EventsRepository.Events - returns me events with many imageslink, but in brouser I doesn't see them:

```
 "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:28286/odata/$metadata#Events","value":[
    {
      "Title":"Title", 
      "Description":"Description"
    },...
```

I know that Odata have $expand option, but seems it's not supported yet.
How can I force my application to return deep serializable object? Because I want to get all included data in my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ImageLink were modeled as a complex type the response payload for Event would contain ImageLink inline. You could tell the modelbuilder to map ImageLink as a complex type using,

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<ImageLink>();
```

The proper way to do this though is to use $expand. We are working in $select and $expand support right now and should have working bits in the nightly builds early next week.

Comment: Can I subscribe to something to get notification about any changes?

Comment: [This](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/project/feeds/rss?ProjectRSSFeed=codeplex%3a%2f%2fsourcecontrol%2faspnetwebstack) RSS feed has all the source code commits for the aspnetwebstack project. Anyways, I will remember to post a comment here or ping you once we have something.

Comment: $select and $expand is available in the nightly builds now. Check this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/29/using-nightly-nuget-packages-with-asp-net-web-stack.aspx) on how to use our nightly builds.